# Convergence rate of Monte-Carlo variance estimate

Tags: monte-carlo

What is the convergence rate for Monte-Carlo variance estimate for a random variable $X \in {L^q}(\Omega ,R),2 < q < 4$?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in what exactly you are looking for if you want to get answers here.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth, I'm looking for a convergence rate in terms of number of samples. For example, for random variable with the forth moment variance estimate converges as M^(1/2), where M is the number of samples.

Comment: Right. What I meant is: In what norm are you measuring convergence? How do you draw samples for infinite dimensional objects? Etc.